# How do I read a Blood Pressure Measurement Characteristic with Android BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, characteristics

I am trying to get data from Blood Pressure Measurement [characteristic](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.blood_pressure_measurement.xml).
How to get data from it, Pulse Rate for example?
Thanks anyway.

Comment: There are many examples of how to perform a BLE Read Characteristic operation. You have to access a specific service in the GATT Server with a corresponding characteristic which are typically defined by UUIDs. Then you have to perform a BLE Read operation on a specific characteristic. Then the received value from the external device will be triggered in the public void onCharacteristicRead() method in BLE Callback operation. You can find more information here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: yes. it works for many characteristics, but not on Blood Pressure Measurement.

Comment: what exactly did you try?  what did not work?

Comment: Hello there,
Check the service with UUID - 00001810-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, subscribe to the characteristic with id - 00002a35-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. 
Now I am searching a way to parse the info from this characteristic.

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse the values from the characteristic, you can get the value of the characteristic as a byte array. Each byte in the array corresponds to a different value.

My device returned blood pressure values in mmHg and I found that the systolic value was at index 1, the diastolic value was at index 3, and the heart rate was at index 14. After converting these values to integers, I was able to see the same values to what the blood pressure monitor showed.

Comment: That's nice but is that actually documented anywhere? Wireshark has a decoder in its packet dumper but they must have gotten their info from *somewhere*.

Comment: Similar to my situation. Im getting systolic pressure on 1st index, diastolic on 3rd and pulse on 7th but unfortunately I cant find any CONCRETE specification for this byte array values :/